# RHEL 5.3: crontab runs multiple instances of script

Tags: cron

I have a simple script that runs perfectly when used manually. When I entered into my crontab to run at 10 PM each night it appears to run several instances of the script, and times out my server. Any ideas?

- 22 * * * /mnt/myscript.sh

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong. It should've been 
00 22 * * /mnt/myscript.sh.

Read about crons here.

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-autotasks.html

Comment: Thank you so much my friend. Simple!